What is required for Oracle Data tools and VS 2022?
Cannot get oracle data tools to connect in VS 2022
Will not connect using odp.net managed driver
keep getting "ORA-12545  unable to resolve connect hostname"
will connect using legacy ,net Framework Data Provider for Oracle
I have latest VS2022,  just installed ODT.
I have 2 clients installed 12.2 for 32 bit and 23.4 instaclient for 64 bit
I tried to create connection using managed driver but got error above.
if i use legacy .net  data provider, it connects.

UPDATE:  I realized that managed providers do not depend on a separate client. (instaclient).  With some experimentation, I found that there is an unreported inner exception regarding KERBEROS  auth services.  I disabled KERBEROS and then i was able to connect.
No where did I see in the documentation  that Managed 64 bit does not support Kerberos yet.  I had to dig around for a day to find it.
